# Using Linux bash in Windows 10 to introduce Linux R interpreter to Rstudio (Windows application) .

Tags: r, linux, windows, bash, rstudio

I have a real problem with Unicode in Windows. So I just use Linux. Now I want to know if there is any innovative way to use Microsoft R Open which is installed on Linux bash as the interpreter in RStudio in Windows 10.
I know I can install an X Server on Linux bash but I want it to work in native Windows application.
Maybe [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6rhYvKWbbw) is needed for inspiration. 
Have smart minds any idea?

Comment: One approach would be to install RStudio Server within your Linux VM, and then connect to that using your web browser from the host machine.

Comment: @Kevin Ushey  Have you tried it? I can't make it work. I  think it is impossible for now. [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/212529588-Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows-10-and-Rstudio-Server-Community-edition)

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to run `RStudio Server` on `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` by installing `opencpu` and `RStudio Server`.

Please follow https://www.opencpu.org/download.html instructions.

Tested on Windows 10 Build 16299 with
opencpu-2.0 and rstudio-server-1.1.383-amd64

Answer (score 0):

Install RStudio with [conda](https://anaconda.org/r/rstudio), and stick to the Anaconda channels. They [use MS Open R](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/company-blog/introducing-microsoft-r-open-as-default-r-for-anaconda-distribution/).

See also:

https://www.guru99.com/download-install-r-rstudio.html